# Nodemailer connection Error only on server

Tags: javascript, node.js, outlook, smtp, nodemailer

I am using nodemailer to send mails from nodejs project and for mailing service using outlook service provided by godaddy and its working fine on my local server but as soon as i shifted my project to production server it gives error as stated down

**Error Received**

```
0|node  | {"message":"message - Connection timeout, stack trace - Error: Connection timeout\n    at SMTPConnection._formatError (/var/www/html/dev/project/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:784:19)\n    at SMTPConnection._onError (/var/www/html/dev/project/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:770:20)\n    at Timeout._connectionTimeout.setTimeout (/var/www/html/dev/project/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:235:22)\n    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)\n    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)\n    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)\n    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)","level":"error"}
0|node  | { Error: Connection timeout
0|node  |     at SMTPConnection._formatError (/var/www/html/dev/project/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:784:19)
0|node  |     at SMTPConnection._onError (/var/www/html/dev/project/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:770:20)
0|node  |     at Timeout._connectionTimeout.setTimeout (/var/www/html/dev/project/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:235:22)
0|node  |     at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
0|node  |     at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
0|node  |     at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
0|node  |     at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10) code: 'ETIMEDOUT', command: 'CONN' }
```

**Node Mailer Configurations used**

```
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
host: "smtp.office365.com",
secureConnection: true,
port: 587,
service: 'Godaddy',
debug: false,
auth: {
  user: USER_NAME,
  pass: PASSWORD
}
```

});

Comment: What is the production server that you are trying to use? And are the ports open on the production server for SMTP?

Comment: yes ports are enabled for SMTP

Comment: Change the value of secure to false and try.

Comment: tried already, still same issue

Comment: What is the server that you are using?

Comment: amazon web service EC2

Comment: What's the OS that you are using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226300/discussion-between-mohit-b-and-pronoy999).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: it is not safe to share your Authentication credentials.

First: go to your office and enable email apps accessing

Second: enabling secure property means you enable TLS so make sure you applied TLS correctly from this link https://nodemailer.com/smtp/

Comment: this are not actual auth creds ;)
and for TLS i have tried that too but i'm not sure about correct configurations 
`tls: {ciphers:'SSLv3'},`
is anything else is required

Comment: try to remove secure and tls properties and add this one instead
secureConnection: true,